# How to remove all virtualenv vscode python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Every time i create a new project in vscode there is missing virtual environment.
So i have to do every time `pipenv install requests` (btw, can i install it one time and just use?)

I have created too many of them and they are automatically created in different places, only, last one created in subfolder.
How can i access them on Mac and delete?
[image: Envs]

Comment: you can reuse a virtual environment and set the pythonpath setting to the virtenv, it can be global or workspace setting

Comment: I actally don't use `pipenv` at all. tbh there are too many tools for creating virtual environments in Python, it really is a mess. For example there's also `poetry` and `virtualenvwrapper` - too many tools that unnecessarily complicate and *over-burden* the management of virtual envrionments! My preference is to just plain old `venv` folder localized to each repo directory setup by a simple `virtualenv` call, and add a line in `~/.bash_profile` which activates the virtual environment as soon as you `cd` into it. Easy peasy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For delete unused venvs, in terminal:

```
$ cd ~/.local/share/virtualenvs
$ rm -rf yelp2*
$ rm -rf test*
```

For creating one time use venvs for common projects create a directory for your virtual environments. I use `~/.venvs`.
In `.venvs` directory create your venv. Do the following for vscode can recognize your .venvs directory.

F1 > Open Settings (JSON)

```
"python.venvFolders": [
        "~/.venvs",
    ],
```

After that you can select your venv from Command Palette.

Also take a look at [vscode doc python settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_general-settings)

Comment: i added settings and created a folder. how can i automatically create there when project starts?

Comment: create a virtualenv in the new folder `python -m venv venv_name` and select it from vscode. open a new terminal for activation.